# Initialize AngularJS Service to wire up event handler

Tags: angularjs

I need my Angular Service to be initialized when the app is bootstrapped so it can respond to "some global event". The subscribe method here just wires up a handler that needs to be listening after the app starts.

How can I fire off the "init" function when the app loads?

If I'm off track with my approach please let me know which direction I should go!

```
app.service('serviceName', ['someOtherService', function(someOtherService) {
    this.init = function() {
        subscribe("someEvent", this.someEventHandler);
    };

    this.someEventHandler = function(data) {
        //do stuff
    };
}]);
```

Edit:
Adding more info on my use case:

The event handler that I am subscribing to is from a websocket channel that I'm subscribed to on the server. I want to start listening for events as soon as possible. I'm not really concerned about the DOM at all at this point.

What would be cool is if there was a constructor for the service that I could wire up this event in.

Comment: If I weren't using Angular, I'd probably just create a revealing module that is a immediately invoked function expression. That way when the file is loaded by the browser the object is made available and I can execute whatever initialization logic. So "app loads" could be when the file is loaded by angular/browser.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on something that will work (for my use case) in the docs:

Check out the run function off of the module definition: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies

> Run blocks - get executed after the injector is created and are used to kickstart the application. Only instances and constants can be injected into run blocks. This is to prevent further system configuration during application run time.